# OPEN SSL AES-256-CBC outdated?

Tags: openssl, key

I'm trying to use this command on my Linux terminal:

**openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -a -in file.key -out decrypted.key pass:password**

and it has a Warning: depreciated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.

How can I use the suggested key derivation? And also, the key I am decrypting is already old.

Comment: For decryption, you could try following: 

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -salt -in file.key -out decrypted.key`

Then you you would be prompt to enter aes-256-cbc decryption password

Answer (score 0):

As mentionend under https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities, for decryption in your case, you could try something similar to the following:

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -salt -in file.key -out decrypted.key`

Then you would be prompt to enter aes-256-cbc decryption password

Hopefully, this will help you out!